# Is the multiplication in the ring of functions which are flat at the origin a surjective map?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, reference-request

Denote by $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the ring of all smooth functions which are flat at the origin, i.e
\begin{align}C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n):=\{f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)|\forall i_1, \dots ,i_n \in \mathbb{N}_0 : \partial_1^{i_1}\dots \partial_n^{i_n}f(0)=0\} 
\end{align}
In particular we have
\begin{align}f\in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n) \ \Rightarrow f(0)=0
\end{align}
Let $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be equipped with the standard ring structure induced from the ring of functions. Is the multiplication
\begin{align}C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)\times C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)&\to C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)\\(f,g)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ &\mapsto \ \ \ f\cdot g
\end{align}
a surjective map?

What are (standard) references in the literature, where this type on non-unital rings are discussed?

Comment: What do you mean by "flat at the origin"?

Comment: Flat at the point $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$, so all partial derivatives of a function evaluated at $0$ should vanish.

Comment: Are these real valued smooth functions? In which case $(f, 1) \mapsto f \cdot 1 = f$, where $1$ is the constant function with value $1$, would show its surjective.

Comment: Yes, these are real valued smooth functions. Ah, I see, I was a bit unprecise here. With all partial derivaties I also mean that the function itself should vanish at $0$ so in particular $f(0)=0$, hence the constant function $1$ is not an element in $C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$. I am sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root of a smooth non-negative function need not be smooth - see
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105438/square-root-of-a-positive-c-infty-function. A "flat at the origin" function has to decay quickly at the origin but this is not a sufficient condition for smoothness: the derivatives have to decay as well. So I think any such factorization has to be engineered as below rather than given by a formula using square roots as in the accepted answer by @Stephen Montgomery-Smith.

I'll assume $n=1$ to make the notation easier - the extra dimensions don't add any significant difficulties. Fix $h\in C^\infty_0(\mathbb R).$

I want to construct a smooth function $G:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that the functions $|x|^{-G(\log |x|)}$ and $f |x|^{G(\log |x|)},$ extended to take the value $0$ at the origin, are in $C^\infty_0(\mathbb R).$

Define $G$ on integers by setting $G(k)=0$ for $k\leq 0$ and, inductively, for $k\geq 0,$ set $G(k+1)=G(k)+1$ if $|f^{(i)}(x)|\leq |x|^{-G(k)}$ for all $i\in\{0,1,\dots,G(k)\}$ and all $0<|x|\leq e^{-k},$ and $G(k+1)=G(k)$ otherwise. Crucially, $G(k)$ must increase eventually because if $i$ and $p$ are fixed, $|x|^{p}f^{(i)}(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ by a Taylor series approximation of $f^{(i)}(x).$ So $G(k)\to\infty$ as $k\to\infty.$

Extend $G$ to $\mathbb R$ by fixing a smooth function $s:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $s(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $s(x)=1$ for $x\geq 1$ and defining $G(k+t)=G(k)+(G(k+1)-G(k))s(t)$ for integers $k$ and reals $0<t<1.$
This ensures that the derivatives of $G$ are bounded: $\max G^{(i)}=\max s^{(i)}$ for $i\geq 1.$

All the derivatives of $|x|^{-G(\log |x|)}$ are finite sums of terms each of which is $|x|^{-G(\log |x|)}$ multiplied by some power of $1/|x|,$ some power of $\log |x|,$ and some derivatives of $G.$ Because $G(\log |x|)\to\infty$ as $x\to 0,$ we know that $|x|^{-G(\log |x|)}$ is eventually smaller than any fixed power of $1/|x|,$ which ensures that all these terms tend to zero.

Derivatives of $f |x|^{G(\log |x|)}$ are finite sums of terms each of which has the form $f^{(k)} |x|^{G(\log |x|)}$ for some $k,$ multiplied by some powers of $1/|x|$ and $\log |x|$ and derivatives of $G.$ We've arranged that $f^{(k)} |x|^{G(\log |x|)}$ is eventually smaller than any power of $1/|x|,$ so each term tends to zero.

I don't know if this type of factorization has been studied, but people have tried to characterize ideals of smooth functions. One place to start is Whitney, H. (1948). On ideals of differentiable functions. American Journal of Mathematics, 70(3), 635-658. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372203

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and for pointing out my mistake! I was completely unaware of the references you mentioned, and given the references I was indeed not careful enough when accepting the answer.

Comment: I don't this invalidates my answer.  I take square roots of functions that are strictly positive except at the origin, and at the origin are flat.

Comment: And I think you might be using different notions of flat.  The OP means all derivatives are 0.  I am not sure what this paper means by it: http://www.cmls.polytechnique.fr/perso/bony/BBCP_jfa.pdf but since he defines 2-flat to mean all up to the second derivative are zero, I think he might mean $f(x) = 0$ implies $f'(x) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, that paper uses flat to mean $f'(x) = 0$.  Look at the counterexamples in Theorem 1.2.  They are all polynomials.